# Dúvidas sobre API

Tags: api, restful

Para realizar algumas requisições á API é necessário que você esteja logado no site. Entretanto, eu não tinha ideia de como fazer isso, pois sabia que API não tem sessões. Então, fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei os tokens de acesso (API Tokens) e implementei na minha aplicação. Basicamente, ao termino do login era gerado um token que era salvado na db, e mais tarde quando uma requisição  era feita à API, era comparado o que foi enviado nos parametros e o que tinha na database para verificação. Um amigo me alertou que era gambiarra e também percebi que algumas empresas não utilizam deste método.

Qual seria o metódo mais correto para resolver esse problema? Usar JWT seria uma boa?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, JWT é uma abordagem que está em alta. O ponto é que JWT é um especificação Open de codificação / decodificação de JSON tokens. Por si só ela não define como vc vai utilizar.

O legal do JWT é que vc não precisa de um banco de dados e com isso para um modelo de autenticação só usando criptografia vc pode validar o acesso deixando assim realmente sua API stateless.

Outro abordagem muito utilizada é o protocolo OAuth, pois existem muitos provedores e muitos aplicativos que fazem uso de autenticação usando provedores de recurso de terceiros como: Facebook, LinkedIn e Google.

Para maiores informações:

[OAuth Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)
[JWT](https://jwt.io/)